# Get only one product category term for a WooCommerce product

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, taxonomy-terms

I have a mystery with the categories from WooCommerce.
For different products I have multiple categories.
For example the product **Nike Air Red**
I connect this product with two categories **Brands->Nike** and **Shoes->Red**
Brands and Shoes are main categories and Nike and Red are subcategories.

On the product page I have the following code

```
$terms = wp_get_post_terms( $post->ID, 'product_cat' );
foreach ($terms as $term) {
    echo $term->name;
}
```

The output is NikeRed

Is there a way to get one category?
Nike or Red?

I tried also

```
get_ancestors(get_queried_object_id(), 'product_cat')
```

But this array is empty

Comment: @LoicTheAztec I tried `$terms = wp_get_post_terms( $post->ID, 'product_cat', array('parent' => '0') );` but this returns both categories Nike and Red. I want just one of these

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use `reset()` to get the first term as follows:

```
$term_names = wp_get_post_terms( $post->ID, 'product_cat' array('fields' => 'names') );
echo reset($term_names);
```

This will display the first term name.

And using `end()` will display the last one:

```
$term_names = wp_get_post_terms( $post->ID, 'product_cat' array('fields' => 'names') );
echo end($term_names);
```